# JavaFX ObjectProperty that fires change events even if newValue == oldValue

Tags: java, inheritance, javafx, overriding

`ObjectPropertyBase` skips value invalidation when `newValue == oldValue`:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public void set(T newValue) {
    if (isBound()) {
        throw new java.lang.RuntimeException((getBean() != null && getName() != null ?
                getBean().getClass().getSimpleName() + "." + getName() + " : ": "") + "A bound value cannot be set.");
    }
    if (value != newValue) {
        value = newValue;
        markInvalid();
    }
}
```

**Problem:** `markInvalid()` and `value` are `private`, therefore I cannot override `set(newValue)` properly.

**Question:** How can I obtain a type, that does **not** do the `(value != newValue)` check?

This question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45081431/javafx-update-events-from-objectproperty-just-like-in-obvervablelist).

Comment: if your value type is used only here you can make a dirty hack by making `equals()` be always false. :)

Comment: Did you try invalidation listeners?

Comment: MouseEvent, its the same thing, thanks for taking time!

Comment: If the answer solved your problem please consider accepting it by checking the green checkmark to its left.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I obtain a type, that does not do the (value != newValue) check?

Extend `SimpleObjectProperty` (or `ObjectPropertyBase`) and override its `set` method and skip the check. While you can't call `markInvalid` yourself, the method doesn't do much you can't do:

```
class InvalidatingObjectProperty<T> extends SimpleObjectProperty<T> {

    @Override
    public void set(T newValue) {
        if (isBound()) {
            throw new java.lang.RuntimeException(
                    (getBean() != null && getName() != null ? getBean().getClass().getSimpleName() + "." + getName() + " : " : "")
                            + "A bound value cannot be set.");
        }
        invalidated();
        fireValueChangedEvent();
    }
}
```

What we're missing is setting `valid` to `false`. However, the only place where that matters is in its `toString` method, which you can override as well.

Comment: Did you mean `SimpleObjectProperty` or `ObjectPropertyBase`? (You wrote the same thing twice - `ObjectPropertyBase`).