# TreeTableView doesn't refresh data - JavaFX 21

Tags: javafx, java-21

This question was asked a few times here but none of the solutions work for me, maybe because of the latest version or other issues.

I have an object with few properties, one of which changes when a response comes back from the network. I would like to update the tree dynamically when a new value arrives (this can be cell by cell). from what I was reading you should use the StringProperty class to represent observable value.

Things I tried:

- Registering the column using this property,
- Adding an event listener to the property and triggering a tree update

```
public interface PropertyState {
    StringProperty stateProperty();
```

and the Tree Item (I used this from another SO answer...)

```
public class TableItem extends TreeItem<PropertyState> {
    public TableItem(PropertyState state) {
        super(state);
        state.stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldName, newName) -> {
           TreeModificationEvent<PropertyState> event =
               new TreeModificationEvent<>(TreeItem.valueChangedEvent(), this);
           Event.fireEvent(this, event);
        });
    }
}
```

Then lastly the tree view table:

```
TreeTableColumn<PropertyState, String> state = new TreeTableColumn<>("State");
state.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getValue().stateProperty());

getColumns().add(state);
// more code to populate the tree with objects
```

So whatever I try, the cell value does not change. I can trace the network back and the StringProperty does change but the event is never triggered and the cell keeps the original value.

Seemed some wrapper or cloning was going on... Any help would be appreciated.

Made a simple code example as requested. this seemed to work fine so must have a bug in my original code.

https://github.com/gadieichhorn/78152140/tree/master

Comment: That `TreeItem` subclass (and the listener it adds) _should_ be completely unnecessary. Your cell value factory should be enough. Also, you mention you've confirmed the property value changes. Can you provide a [mre] of this (without a real network call)? Note that the property, because you've linked it to the UI, **must** only be updated on the FX Thread.

Comment: TreeTableView is the most complex of views in JavaFX and not something I work with much, so there may be some differences.  However, for other things like a TableView, the standard way to trigger changes to a cell is to use an [extractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517082/when-observablelist-generate-update-change-event) defined on the underlying list.  When the dependent property changes, the updateItem method of the cell will be fired and the value will update.  You don't need to add additional complex, broken listeners that create and fire custom events.

Comment: @jewelsea Does `[Tree]TableView` not listen to the observable returned by the cell value factory? If it does, then the extractor should not be necessary.

Comment: @Slaw thanks for the comment, I only have one thread for now (how can I validate this??. good to know. I think there is something else going on.

Comment: *"Made a simple code example as requested. this seemed to work fine so must have a bug in my original code."* -> I'm inclined to close the question as not reproducible.  Remote help for something which cannot be reproduced is pretty difficult.

Comment: Create and post a [mre]